# blender kill particles not viewing in render

Tags: rendering, particles, render-layers

I am making a harry potter video with friends and I'm adding magic between the 2 wands. I'm using 2 particle systems with gravity off pulled by a force field for the magic and killing them when they hit the center with an invisible circle with collision kill particles. it looks great in the viewport but when I render it doesn't kill the particles.
in the beginning, I thought it had to do with the 2 view layers I have so that a stone wall will be clear and the magic will be blurred and will have haze without volumetrics but my moving it around trying to solve the problem didn't seem to help.

viewport -
[image: this is what it looks like in the viewport]

render-[image: and this is what it looks like in the render]

there is a circle with kill particles
[image: notice the circle in the center, it has kill particals]

these are the collision settings
[image: these are the collision settings]

view layer 1 outliner (blur + haze)
[image: view layer 1 outliner (blur + haze)]

view layer 2 outliner (stone wall)
[image: view layer 2 outliner (stone wall)]

I don't think it has anything to do with it but here is the compositing (maybe has to do with rendering or something) -
[image: compositing]

and lastly here is the blend file -
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P8E1CuaPaVcRmHLIN59RoRzWov3QwpWW

Comment: no, I'm trying to make it not look like in the rendered picture in which the particles don't stop and die from the collision object

Comment: they just keep on going

Comment: Ok. I just notices that.

Comment: do you know how to solve it?

Comment: It looks like your particles may be colliding with the force sphere in the middle. What are your settings for it. I can't download the .blend file because I use 2.79.      From what I saw in the solid view, the particles are actually slightly visible after colliding, so if you can see them bouncing off in rendered view, then you will see them in the render.

Comment: Do you already tried caching the particles to disk? (Particle Properties > Cache > Disk Cache) @JBlock

Comment: That is a good idea though

Comment: "Do you already tried caching the particles to disk? (Particle Properties > Cache > Disk Cache) @JBlock" – brockmann
yeah and it crashed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent internal or viewport cache errors, save your particle cache to the disk before rendering. Enable *Disk Cache* under *Particle Properties > Cache* and click *Bake all Dynamics*:

[image] 
*Cache panel*

[image] 
*Frame 7200 - 7325 cached to disk and rendered with Eevee*

For several reasons but mostly because of the colour range provided by some of the available image formats, I suggest render your animation to an *image sequence* (preferably `.exr`) and compile the images into a video container like `.mov`, `.mp4` or `whatever` afterwards.

Comment: Same Issue came up today again: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165640/31447

Comment: The answer to this question that you have provided is virtually identical to my answer.

Comment: Any arguments or facts to support your statement? @Nate_Sycro27

Comment: No. Just that it is not really a good idea to post another answer containing similar material to the former answer previously posted. I.e. .png image sequencing.

Comment: I would never suggest rendering to png (worst file format ever) and havn't done that here (fact) so what's your point? @Nate_Sycro27

Comment: when I tried that it didn't even slow down or anything like that it immediately closed the window. my graphics card didn't struggle it just was like pressing the x button - immediate close

Comment: I tried it in the beginning and when you said disk cache thought it might be that but it crashed.

Comment: I tried both 2.8 and 2.81 with the same result

Comment: thank you very much for caching it I will use your caching and test on another machine. thanks

Comment: No problem. Keep me posted @JBlock

Comment: do you know how to import a cache? I did external and found the folder but it says "no valid data to read!"

Comment: didn't find online

Comment: On the run writing a few instructions and testing the process I found an open bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T68290 ... Bad news: it seems we can not exchange any particles caches for now, there is an error finding the correct point count. You'll have to find a machine which is able to cache them and render them in one go as I did yesterday. I'm sorry @JBlock

Comment: thanks though. appreciate the attempt

Comment: When rendering as a .jpeg or most other image formats, windows (my computer) is not able to read the sequenced video file, so I would recommend .png.

Comment: Doesn't explain your statement, still waiting. Otherwise it would be nice, you would remove your comments... Anyway, I suggest take your time, listen to the others, think about your attitude and learn some of the necessary basics instead of trying to simulate water, smoke or emulate a microscope using lux: One of them is e.g.: *png is the worst file format ever for this kind of work (as already mentioned)* and you always want to use *OpenExr*. [First post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106671/31447) that I've found *for you* and there is more for sure. @Nate_Sycro27

Answer (score 1):

### **Note: You are using EEVEE**

I tried your settings, and it worked fine for me in Cycles. I noticed that you are using EEVEE for rendering, and if you want to escape volumetrics by using compositioning then you should use cycles.

**If you want to** continue using EEVEE, then I would recommend using volumetrics, as opposed to compositioning.

However, if you **do** switch to cycles, then you *can* use compositioning for achieving a "volume" look.

When I tried your .blend on another PC, the particles ***did not*** continue to show bouncing off of the cylinder when using cycles, (which is what I thought you want), so that must be the answer.

If that *doesn't* fix it, try rendering as a png sequence, and then using the video sequencer.

Comment: that didn't solve it. my problem isn't the volume its that when rendering the animation it ignored the kill particles collision object which it calculated when in the viewport. thanks though.

Comment: Have you tried png image sequencing? There have been many problems with people that straight up render animation video output.

Comment: cool that also worked thank you