# Particles render at origin every other frame when they shouldn't

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles

I was curious if anyone else had run into this or knows what could cause this.  So basically I have a scene and in the middle of the render some particles are created.  However, during the part with the particles, every other frame shows them at the base plane they exude from instead of where they should be.  So when it's finally rendered it looks like its flashing, going back between how it should function and being stuck to the plane. Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys! I'm using the Cycles render engine.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to bake them: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165640/31447 Seems there are some caching issues in latest versions.

Comment: Perfect! Seems to be working so far.. If you want to submit this as an answer Ill give you the credit