# Blender 2.83 Cant see particles in render

Tags: particles

I am brand new to Blender coming from Maya and I can't figure out why I can't see my particles in the render. Am I missing something?

The *Emitter*, *Domain* and *Collision Object* all look good in the Viewport, but the *Render View* does not show any particles. I needed foam and spray.

Thanks

Comment: first guess, did you assign any material to the emitted object (not the emitter object)? Particles do not need domain, as domain is mainly for fluid and smoke simulations. You should share the blender file so anyone could help you out.

Comment: Try to cache them: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165625/2-81a-particles-in-render-not-matching-preview/165640#165640

Comment: I have the same problem as @paulepc; i searched already around and even cam across a post stating that cycles does not support particles (*scratch head*)... Simple setup: http://www.filedropper.com/noparticles   - added particles and clicked bake; i tried different setups (create cache on disk, etc but non of the render engines render the particles - yes I also tried adding a material). What else could i try? Maybe someone could have look at the blend file...

Comment: Ok, in my case the problem was, that i choose under rendering: halo - watch this until about 2:55 min and you will know what to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gepD8FgcXJQ

Answer (score 1):

I just changed my emitter to Plane and that solved my problem.