# Eevee crashes when trying to render two animated particle systems

Tags: rendering, animation, particles, eevee-render-engine

I need to render 200 frames during which two particle systems are animated (the Scale setting in Particle system's render tab, and the rendering visibility for the most part). Everything is fine in the viewport, and also in rendered preview mode.

Eevee manage to render any frame during which **those specific two** particle systems are not animated. I also have other particle systems around but I've never had rendering problems so far.

When I click render, or press F12, the render window opens, then Blender closes itself...

Any help ? :( Is this a known bug ?

Comment: Hi, probably scene has become too complex but impossible to know because you have not shared any images of interface, settings, or scene. Please [edit] your question and add enough information that other users can see what the issue is that you are dealing with. The current version of your question is too unclear. Thanks

Comment: Agree with Timaroberts. Wild guess: There are child particles enabled and your hardware is not able to handle that amount of points. I'd suggest to bake them in the first place if you haven't already: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165640/31447

Comment: Hey guys! I'm using Blender 2.91.0. And yeah, I know there's a lack of infos in my post, as I want to avoid to share my project as much as possible (I'm bounded by commercial use...). I'm running Blender with a Ryzen 7 3700X and a RTX 2060. In this scene, there's 3 particles systems (2 of them are animated as stated in my post, and the last one makes the particles rotate), all of this in a low density volumetric emitter for lighting purposes. So yes, there's a lot to calculate but as I said everything works fine in rendered mode (6fps) and solid mode (20fps).

Comment: As a sidenote : Is it possible to bake Hair particles ? I know there's a Cache tab in the emitter mode, but I can''t find it with the Hair particle system.Also, I wish you both a merry christmas, and a happy end of the year :)

Comment: Ok I've simplified things in my scene (a couple of meshes used as reference in the Render tab of my particle systems had modifiers on it, then shape keys, so I've applied modifiers), and there's only 1 frame I can't render. Nothing happens at that frame in term of animation (no keyframe beginning nor ending). Wtf

Comment: It renders well on Blender 2.83, but not with 2.90 nor 2.91... 
By the way, I opened Blender in debug mode thanks to a command line, and it crashed just after rendering everything on the scene and right at the time when it should display "wm_window_make_drawable: set drawable 1" in the console.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete your lighting cache and rebuild it before rendering it again. Try with lower cubemap sizes, lower diffuse occlusion size, and lower cube size and cascade size for shadows. Haven't tried reducing the 'Dots' in Irradiance volume's , but do try if everything still fails.

Also if possible, since most particles-related renders are related to 'abstract' theme - like simulations or Logo-intros, try rendering without baking the indirect lighting cache. Rendering without baked lights must work.