# Do I need to optimize PNGs after I will output them from Blender and before I will import them to video editing software?

Tags: rendering, animation

I want to make animation in Blender. It will be transition for video. In video editing software I will put this animation over junction of two parts of video.

In Blender I will make output as PNG sequence. Next step I will import PNG sequence to some video editing software. Maybe OpenShot, Shotcut, Kdenlive, DaVinci Resolve. Maybe some else.

Do I need to optimize PNGs after I will output them from Blender and before I will import them to video editing software?

Comment: Never ever render to png. Render to OpenEXR: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106671/31447

Comment: @brockmann Thank you, brockmann. I took in attention your words. I took in attention the material you pointed. In https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106670/compositors-corner-pin-node-does-something-odd-to-input-image/106671#106671 troy_s wrote _"their alpha values are unassociated by design"_. What does it mean?

Comment: @Konskoo *Unassociated (straight) alpha* offers less precision compared to Associated (premultiplied). This leads to ugly borders between transparent/opaque areas.  [Wikipedia - Alpha Compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you, Jachym. I took in attention your words. I took in attention the information in Wikipedia - Alpha Compositing. I want to use more precision. Because of it I want to use associated (premultiplied) alpha. Does in OpenEXR associated (premultiplied) alpha set as default?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about using blender.

Comment: @RayMairlot Ray, this question is about using blender. About output from Blender. I received many useful information from answers. And I want to clarify few details. I want to continue discussion in this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, assuming by optimize you mean with an optimizer such as [pngcrush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush). These optimizers are designed to strip out extra information in the file in order to reach the smallest acceptable file size, which seems unlikely to matter much for files that will only be used while you're editing your video. If optimizing accomplishes anything, it'll be to optimize away information which might have been useful when making further tweaks in your video editor.

As [brockmann pointed out in the comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/do-i-need-to-optimize-pngs-after-i-will-output-them-from-blender-and-before-i-wi#comment297555_177513), using EXR is preferable to PNG, if your video editing software supports it.