# Exporting PNG Animation With Shadows On Transparent Background

Tags: animation, export, shadows

I'm doing an animation and trying to export it as a PNG. I need to export it with the shadows, but on a transparent background. Once the render finished I imported of on the PNG sequence to see if the shadow was included but it wasnt. Is there a method to have the shadows exported with my PNG animation?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: There is no shadow catcher option in eevee, you would have to fake it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQJ_SBpcUQE Also: never ever render to png, recommend render to OpenEXR, especially when dealing with alpha: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106670/compositors-corner-pin-node-does-something-odd-to-input-image/106671#106671

Comment: Yes, great information, thanks!