# Disable default animation output when using "File output" nodes

Tags: python, compositing-nodes

I'm using a "File output" node to customize the output of my animation (separating object & shadow into two files for each frame).

I have set custom path for the File output node and subpaths for its inputs. This works fine.

But Blender also writes a second copy of the animation frames using the default "Output" setting in the main "Output properties" panel. How can I get rid of that?

So far the best thing I can do is to delete the output:

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = "//ignore/"
#
# render the animations here...
#
shutil.rmtree('ignore')
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot disable the default output... I usually set the default to jpg. However, I'd consider using exr and piz encoding: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148231/what-image-format-encodes-the-fastest-or-at-least-faster-png-is-too-slow/148466#148466 if you are dealing with alpha you should consider exr anyway: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106671/31447

Comment: Have the same issue in the current Blender version and there is probably still no ideal solution. The default output can even accidentally overwrite the result of the File Output node if both are using the same file name and file format.

Comment: Any solutions on this?. I'm working on a huge scene and this temporary files are anoying...extra work for disks...

Comment: No. You could use the method in the answer below, it if still works. Or output in a folder and run a script that clears it out on a regular timer. Discussions have been happening [on Blender's bug tracker](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/57699), but so far no design solutions have been made.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem and I think to found a temporary solution.
Basically I though to use the directory of Windows RecycleBin as output
( C:\$Recycle.Bin\Cestino\  ...that is...  C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1238235524-1654077969-1323641347-1004\ ).

Unexpectedly the trash remain empty! …it doesn’t appears the renders files inside of trash, like this directory for Blender is a sort of implicit command to destroy immediatly the generated files!
However…I hope it can be for all of you, a temporary solution, waiting for a real fix of this bug.