# Generating RGB,EXR or Both on demand using Blender Python

Tags: python, .exr, depth-map

I am trying to generate a python script for rendering RGB and/or an EXR file(for getting the mist pass) for spherical images using blender.

So I have a scene and I am using the cycles rendering engine. I want to save the OpenExr file and/or the RGB file based on the input that the user gives (for which I am using a JSON file).

For the mist pass I am using a setup similar to the following link:
[Getting the depth of every pixel to the center of projection of the camera in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238218/getting-the-depth-of-every-pixel-to-the-center-of-projection-of-the-camera-in-bl)

I am using the following lines of code for creating and saving the renders.

```
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath=output_path+str(i)
bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True,write_still=True)
```

However, the above lines of code save both the RGB image as well as the EXR file.
In order to render just the RGB images I have used the following in addition to the above lines of code and that works well:

```
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = False
```

However, I am not able to generate just the OpenEXR file. Simply using the following also didn't help :

`bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)`

Can someone guide me with this and/or suggest a better way for the same?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to disable the default output (if that's your question) -> [Disable default animation output when using "File output" nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189869/disable-default-animation-output-when-using-file-output-nodes).

Comment: Ohh ... that's bad. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem @Sourabh. Suggest set the default output to jpg and remove the file if necessary using python.

Comment: what happens if you set the File Output node's path to the name of the exr file?  2 files, an error, or just 1?