# How to composite an image sequence rendered in PNG?

Tags: image, compositing-nodes

I've rendered my first image sequences of 119 frames in PNG.
I have trouble to use the compositor in order to save the final video file.

When I load the image sequence (with the image sequence node) I just have access to Image, Alpha and Depth output.

However when I rendered my sequence, I did enable many passes, like emmision, trans, diff...

Is there a way I could get access to these passes or is it too late?

I really want to use the glare option, but when I add it, it doesn't do any effect on my render.

I attached a screen of the nodes I added.
[image]
Thank you for your help and pieces of advice!

V

Comment: Never ever render to png, recommend render to OpenEXR especially when dealing with alpha: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106671/31447

Answer (score 1):

If your redered correctly, you should have an image sequece for each of the passes (image Sequence Emision, Image Sequence Diffuse, Image sequence Shadows and so on) if you only turn it on but did not save the passes, you need to start again. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+how+to+output+passes