# Rendering stuck at 99%

Tags: eevee-render-engine

When I render an animation it gets to the final frame of it but then freezes, I cannot save it or do anything with and when I come out of the rendering tab and back onto the blender layout the rendering bar underneath the keyframes menu is stuck on 99%. I am using the EEVEE rendering because I don't know if I can handle cycles but I have tried it and I get the exact same problem, can someone please suggest something that I can do.

Comment: I guess it's caused by the encoding of the actual animation. I'd suggest render to an image sequence and encode afterwards using ffmpeg or davinci resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Render your animation to png, not as FFMPEG. So you will have your single frame pictures on your hard disc. You can then make a movie out of it with video editing from Blender. If you are just missing one frame of your animation, you still have a 99% of a movie - instead of nothing.
If you want more help you should provide us your .blend file.

Reason for being stuck can be a lot. From you machine has to low memory until it is not stuck, but just calculating ...

Comment: Never ever render to png, recommend render to OpenEXR: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106671/31447

Comment: Thank you for the responses I will try both of them out and I made a compromise of using a .avi file. Also I was saving them as PNG's but I forgot where I'd saved them so I didn't think they had been saved. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: also whats in your compositing section, it has to do some calculations if theres lots of nodes there

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem, both Eevee and Cycles are freezing during render, whether rendering image sequence or ffmpeg. One solution I started was to render the 15 to 20 frames or so before the freeze, force quit blender, then restart blender and start rendering from the point it froze. This worked - it was rendering the frames correctly, but just kept freezing. However, using blender headless mode (command prompt) I was able to render the entire animation without issue. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

Comment: Why force quit blender? As long as it's not frozen you can stop rendering by hitting ESC or the X next to the render status bar... or if your animation goes from frame 1 to 100, set the end frame to 90 and render the last frames afterwards. You can do that by setting start to 91 and end to 100 or disable _Overwrite_ in the output settings, than Blender automatically begins rendering at 91 even if start is set to 1.

Comment: Because Blender WAS frozen. That's why the render was not progressing. The only solution was to force quit blender since it was pressing escape or clicking the X did nothing.

Comment: Ah okay... I understood the part with rendering the 15 to 20 frames before the freeze as if you were rendering the problematic range and force quit even before Blender was freezing. I got that wrong... Whenever I had this problem I rendered until shortly _before_ it usually froze, stopped rendering, restarted Blender and then continued with a "fresh" and empty memory so the load wasn't that heavy on the GPU's RAM. That helped with cumulating memory load. If the single frames themselves needed too much graphics memory I switched to CPU for the last frames.