# How do I separately apply color correction to a model and video clip?

Tags: modeling, rendering, video, color, tracking

So I'm making a scene where I put my model in a clip I tracked. I think the lighting looks good but the colors of the model itself look overexposed compared to the "flat" colors of the video (this is game footage, that's why it looks flat).


I would like to know how to apply color correction on only the model so that it matches the scene colors. I'm gonna apply overal color correction in other software when rendered to make it look better.


I added a screenshot (quality much better in blender) so u can see what the problem is. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How do you composite them on top of each other? Usually you can cc any image/render/video at any point, just do it before you mix (overlay) them.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz I'm not that good with all the compositing nodes haha, but I didn't render anything yet, this is just the rendered preview. It's the tracked footage set as background and tracking scene setup, with the lighting and animation. Also, I'm planning to use SheepIt renderfarm since 1 frame takes over 40 minutes to render, don't know if that might be a problem?

Answer (score -1):

OK, so here is what I would do:

I would strongly suggest that you render your model and put it on top of your image in 2D by simple image/videocomposite. Render out an exr or png sequence and then re-import that in Blender and use an alpha-over node in the compositor (you can also use any video editing software that way)
Then you can just put your image through any CC nodes and process it before merging.

I would also suggest using EEVEE, since you don't have any detail that relies on caustics. Should turn those 40min into 40s.

And as final tip: If you are using motion blur or depth of field, leave the plane in the background, but turn off camera visibility. This way it will already blend into the blurred areas saving you a lot of fine-tuning.

Comment: png is no option, especially when dealing with alpha there is no other option than exr -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106670/compositors-corner-pin-node-does-something-odd-to-input-image/106671#106671

Comment: While this article clarifies the minor drawback of PNG, it remains an option. If your alpha channel is soft and you don't use it for masking and use the invisible BG trick I mentioned, the filesize trade-off can outweigh the slight alpha issues.

Comment: File size even can be smaller, read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/148466/

Comment: Thank you, that's very in-depth and extremely useful.