# Where can I add Color settings(filmic) for saving .PNG

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, image, filmic-blender

Where should I add this setting for png to export with correct color settings, since now blender by default exports using 'Standard' color profile
I found this line - `bpy.context.scene.view_settings.view_transform = 'Filmic'`, where should I add it?
thank you!

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Image to Photoshop",
    "description": "Send image as new layer of photoshop",
    "version": (0,7),
    "blender": (2, 8, 0),
    "location": "image",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Import-Export"}
 
import bpy
import os
from . import sync_tools

translation_dict = {
    "en_US" :
        {("*", "Send image as layer of photoshop") 
            : "Send image as new layer of photoshop",
        ("*", "Open on Photoshop") 
            : "Image to Photoshop"},

js_name = "img_open.jsx"
 
###################################################
class IMAGE_OT_ToPhotoshop(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Send image as layer of photoshop"""
    bl_idname = "action.to_photoshop"
    bl_label = "Send image as layer of photoshop mjasu"
    def execute(self, context):
        # Generate file path
        img_path  = sync_tools.set_temp_fpath(context,extantion = ".png")
        # Save img file
        bpy.ops.image.save_as(save_as_render=False, copy = True, filepath=img_path, relative_path=True,)
        # execute Photoshop Script
        sync_tools.execute_js(context, js_name, img_path)
        return {'FINISHED'}
 
 
def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("action.to_photoshop", 
        text="Open on Photoshop" )
 
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(IMAGE_OT_ToPhotoshop)
    bpy.types.IMAGE_MT_image.prepend(menu_func)
    bpy.app.translations.register(__name__, translation_dict)
 
def unregister():
    bpy.app.translations.unregister(__name__)
    bpy.types.IMAGE_MT_image.remove(menu_func)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(IMAGE_OT_ToPhotoshop)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
#########################################################
```

Comment: Setting `save_as_render` to `True` should do the trick if CM is set to filmic (it is by default). Doesn't it? `bpy.ops.image.save_as(save_as_render=True)` is the default so I guess there is a reason why the add-on author set it to `False`... Consider that png is the worst file format ever when it comes to CG: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106671/

Comment: thank you very much, I ready your to answer only now but yes, I found out that the save us option set it to my current settings, now all goes great, thank you!